# GROUP BY With ORDER BY ASC & DESC

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table, `spa`, that has most of the information I need:

[image: spa table results preview]

And I join another table, `client`, to grab the `last_name` field:

[image: client table results preview]

What I need is to get the first `room_code`, `service_detail`, & `provider_start_time` for each `sba_date` and `provider_code`, and the **last** `provider_end_time`.

Using my images as examples, the expected result would be:

[image: expected results preview]

Comment: What does "first" mean in terms of ```room_code``` and ```service_detail```? Those corresponding to the minimal ```provider_start_time```?

Comment: And how to match ```client``` with ```spa```? I cannot find a foreign key..

Comment: @Islingre It should be ordered by `provider_start_time`, so `violet`/`deep90` for the 28th, `moon`/`botwater` for the 30th, and `amehty`/`swed60` for the 31st. The tables are joined by `provider_code` and `client_code`. Sorry I forgot to include this!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this can be done with window functions `row_number()` and `last_value()`:

```
select
    room_code,
    service_detail,
    sba_date,
    provider_start_time,
    provider_end_time,
    last_name
from (
    select 
        s.*,
        c.last_name,
        row_number() over(
            partition by s.sba_date, s.provider_code
            order by s.provider_start_time
        ) rn,
        last_value(provider_end_time) over(
            partition by s.sba_date, s.provider_code
            order by s.provider_start_time
            range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
        ) provider_end_time
    from spa s
    inner join client c on c.client_code = s.provider_code
) t
where rn = 1
```

The inner query joins the two tables and ranks the records within groups of records having the same `sba_date` and `provider_code`, by ascending `provider_start_time`; it also computes the last value of the `provider_end_time` within the same group. Then, the outer query filters on the first record in each group.

Comment: it's giving an error on `t`: `The column 'last_name' was specified multiple times for 't'.`

Comment: @WolfieeifloW: in my query, `last_name` appears only once in the subquery and once in the outer query, which is fine. Do you have a column named `last_name` in table `spa`?

Comment: There is a column named `last_name` in table `spa`, yes.

Comment: Well, that's what generates the error. You cannot have two columns with the same name in the subquery. This column does not show in your sample data so I could not tell. To solve this error, you can simply replace `s.*` in the subquery with the list of columns that you want to select (like `s.room_code, s.service_detail, ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use some CTE or sub-query:

```
;WITH cte AS ( --getting min and max time for particular provider on some date
SELECT sba_date,
       MIN(provider_start_time) as provider_start_time,
       MAX(provider_end_time) as provider_end_time,
       provider_code
FROM spa
GROUP BY sba_date, provider_code
)
-- here goes join to clients (last_name) and original table to get room and detail
SELECT s.room_code,
       s.service_detail,
       c.sba_date,
       c.provider_start_time,
       c.provider_end_time,
       cl.last_name
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN client cl
   ON c.provider_code = cl.client_code
INNER JOIN spa s
   ON s.sba_date = c.sba_date0
    AND s.provider_code = c.provider_code
    AND s.provider_start_time = c.provider_start_time
```